# Spring Boot - Sql server no trae resultados y da error

Tags: sql-server, spring-boot, spring

estoy comenzando un proyecto con angular en el front, Spring Boot como backend y SQL server de base de datos. El problema que tengo es que necesito hacer una consulta a la base de datos que me dedvuelva una conjuncion de elementos de tablas (dos inner join) tengo la clase que deberia mapear los resultados que es la siguiente

```
public class ProfesionalModelo {
    private Long idProfesional;
    private Long idPersona;
    private String cuil;
    private String nombre;
    private String apellido;
    private int dni;
    private String descripcion;
    private Persona persona;
    private Especialidad especialidad;

    }
```

Con sus constructores y sus getters y setters (no los pongo para no hacer todo muy largo). Luego tengo el siguiente repositorio:

```
@Repository
public interface ProfesionalModeloRepositorio extends JpaRepository<ProfesionalModelo, Long> {

    @Query(value = "SELECT pro.id_profesional, p.id_persona, p.cuil, p.nombre, p.apellido, p.dni, e.descripcion FROM profesional pro INNER JOIN persona p ON pro.id_persona = p.id_persona INNER JOIN especialidad e ON pro.id_especialidad = e.id_especialidad", nativeQuery = true)

    List<ProfesionalModelo> consultarProfesionales();
}
```

Tampoco pongo las importaciones para no alargar el codigo.
y por ultimo el controlador:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/V1/")
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:4200")
public class ProfesionalModeloControlador {

    @Autowired
    private ProfesionalModeloRepositorio repositorio;

    @GetMapping("/consulta")
    public List<ProfesionalModelo> consultarProfesionales() {
        return repositorio.consultarProfesionales();
    }
}
```

Las consultas a las bases de datos que son "traer todo de una tabla" o traer un elemento de una tabla, sin ningun JOIN y que se coinciden con alguna clase en spring boot funcionan correctamente, pero esta funcion me da el siguiente error:

```
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the condition evaluation report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.      
2023-08-15T12:56:34.111-03:00 ERROR 144 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'profesionalModeloControlador': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'repositorio': Error creating bean with name 'profesionalModeloRepositorio' defined in com.guardias.backend.repositorio.ProfesionalModeloRepositorio defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on JpaRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableJpaRepositoriesConfiguration: Not a managed type: class com.guardias.backend.modelo.ProfesionalModelo
```

Comment: ¿No tienes un servicio en tu modelo?

Comment: no, lo hago directamente entre el el controlador, el repositorio y la clase, asi me funciona con las consultas tipo "select * from....". Necesito un servicio para que funcione este tipo de consultas?